# Sequelize - Promise.All returning array of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

The following query successfully log out queried results:

```
    loans.findAll({
        attributes: option.LoanAttributes,
        include: option.LoanIncludes
      }).then(results => {
      console.log(ExtractQuery(results));
    });
```

However when I wraps it within a `promise.all` function, it returns an array of undefined:

```
    Promise.all([
      loans.findAll({
        attributes: option.LoanAttributes,
        include: option.LoanIncludes
      })
    ]).then(results => {
      console.log(ExtractQuery(results));
    })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Promise.all(promiseArraySizeN).then(fulfilledPromiseArraySizeN)`

You have a promise array of size 1 so it will return a fulfilled promise array of size 1. Therefore you need to check results[0].

```
Promise.all([
  loans.findAll({
    attributes: option.LoanAttributes,
    include: option.LoanIncludes
  })
]).then(results => {
  console.log(ExtractQuery(results[0]))
})
```